# When you create a pointer, why do all variables suddenly get initialized to random values?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    int x;
    printf("%d", x);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This ends up printing 0 no matter how many times I execute it. But if I end up creating a pointer and pointing it to `x`, or actually any variable...

```
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    int x;
    printf("%d", x);


    int *z = &x;
    
    return 0;
}
```

it prints random integer values like `25345`. It doesn't matter where this pointer is initialized, data types like `int` are no longer default initialized to 0.

Comment: Youi're using `foo.b` without ever initializing it, so it's printing random memory content that are at that location when you use it.  `struct a foo;` simply declares a variable that is a structure - it does not initialize the members of that structure. If you change your code to `struct a foo; foo.b  = 12345;`, it will print `Hello world 12345` properly. **Always initialize variables before using them.**

Comment: In other words, it's not initialized to anything. It's pointing to whatever is there at the moment.

Comment: Time to crank up those compiler warnings (and maybe use address sanitizer through the rest of the code). Even just using `x` here is bad and should be fixed.

Comment: You're also using `x` without initializing it, which explains (as much as is possible to do) why one program takes one branch and the other takes the other.

Comment: Forgot to mention: *I can no longer check if a variable is actually initialized to something* - Welcome to C. The only way to tell if a variable has been initialized is to read the code to find the line that initializes it; if you don't find that code, the variable hasn't been initialized. The proper way is to turn on compiler warnings, which will tell you when you make the mistake of using an unitialized variable at compile time.

Comment: Remember, a pointer is just a normal variable that holds the address for something else as its value. That something else -- still must be properly initialized. (in your case `x` is that something else -- and nowhere do you initialize it). Also note, that access of a variable with automatic storage duration while its value is indeterminate is *Undefined Behavior*. So anything could happen when you attempt to access the value of `x` before it is initialized -- the behavior is undefined by the C standard.

Comment: @KenWhite the point i was trying to make is without pointers, it seems like ints get default initialized to 0. But as soon as I create a pointer then it suddenly prints the random memory contents. I simplified the example I used.

Comment: @EricGumba: No, ints don't *get default initialized to 0*. That's nonsense. ints aren't initialized until your code initializes them. Your use of `if(x)` in your code above is just as wrong as your use of `foo.b` was before you edited it out.  **Use of any unitialized variable is undefined behavior - you cannot depend on any value that is contained in that variable. Once again, **ALWAYS initialize variables before using them. ALWAYS.*** And so you don't forget, **ALWAYS initialize variable before using them.**. **ALWAYS** means **every single time**, with NO exceptions.

Comment: @EricGumba: As others have said, it's not initialized. But odds are, without the pointer, the compiler is storing it in a register, without putting it on the stack, and with the pointer, it puts it on the stack (so it has a valid memory address). The register *might* be being zeroed or *might* be naturally zero, but the stack *happens* to be filled with garbage from runtime initialization so the register vs. stack decision changes the *undefined in all circumstances* value.

Comment: And if you enable compiler warnings, your use of the unitialized variable in your new code will result in a warning that you're using an unitialized variable.

Comment: *"This ends up printing 0 no matter how many times I execute it."* - don't bet your life on that, because your code doesn't guarantee it per the standard. You mentioned *"data types like `int` are no longer default initialized to 0."* - they never were in the first place. It may 'seem' like it. It may even seem like it a LOT on your rig. And then... it is turned in to a prof, or worse, a paying customer, and *undefined behavior* inconveniently chooses that particular moment to rear its ugly head. All because of a little `int x;` that should have been an `int x = 0;`

Comment: Before I get beaten by a language lawyer here, I used incorrect terminology. Using a variable that is not initialized is not *undefined behavior*. The proper phrasing is that the value of the variable is *indeterminate*, meaning that it will not contain any meaningful value.

Comment: @KenWhite Actually, using an indeterminate value *is* undefined behavior if the variable in question never had its address taken.  So OP's first code has UB but the second code does not (provided that the value in question is not a trap representation).

Comment: @dbush: Yeah, but if I left it without mentioning *indeterminate*, a C language lawyer would have pounced on me and thrashed me in comments insulting me for my ignorance. I figured I'd better put it in writing here to at least be able to point out I'd corrected myself. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Unless explicitly initialized, the initial value of `auto` variables like `x` is *indeterminate* - it may be `0`, it may be `1234`, it may be `-63124`, it may even be a trap representation.

Space is allocated for the variable, but that space retains whatever bit pattern was last written to it.

*`static`* variables are initialized to `0` or `NULL`.